# applying build modifier in bge

Tags: game-engine, build-modifier

Hello everyone I am a frequent user of this forum however I only made an account recently.

In this basic game I am making as a hobby I have made a HUD with a circle that has have gaps, so that it look digital, I used a build modifier to crate the animation of it going around the center, now the problem I am having is when I apply the modifier it doesn't keep the animation. How would I keep the animation and apply the modifier?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I keep the animation and apply the modifier?

You can't.

## Explanation

Applying a modifier means it converts your setup to a static mesh.

In relation to the BGE there are three ways to it deals with modifiers:

**Supported Modifier**

The BGE can run that modifiers. E.g. the armature modifier.

**Automatically Applied Modifier**

The BGE applies the modifier when loading the scene into a static mesh. This is like the user presses the <kbd>apply</kbd> button.

**Unsupported Modifier**

These modifiers are simply ignored and have no effect (but might disturb the processing of other modifiers).

## Conclusion

In difference to Blender the BGE is not build around Modifiers. To get the effect you want I suggest to look at Logic Bricks (Playing actions, hiding/showing objects, moving object, adding/removing objects).

Comment: I see what you mean, I did have my heart set on the build modifier, but I will try the logic bricks